# How do I create a timer using material UI component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a loading page to delay users while stuff launches before redirecting them to a main dashboard. Using material UI circular progress bar component I want to increment to 100% over a period of 1:15 then redirect the user.

This is what I have for the function:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) => prevProgress + 1);
    }, 1000);

    if (progress >= 100) navigate('/dashboard');

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
```

The progress is shown but it will never redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another `useEffect` for that

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setProgress((prevProgress) => prevProgress + 1);
  }, 1000)

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (progress >= 100) navigate('/dashboard');
}, [progress]);
```